# Find files with a specific 2-line pattern using awk

Tags: command-line, bash, find, awk

I have a few hundreds of files that has this pattern

```
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  2 H18 65.2220 Du 1 RES1 0.0000
@<TRIPOS>BOND
 1  3  5  ar
@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE
```

among them, some of the files are missing the line after the `@<TRIPOS>BOND` and they look like

```
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  2 H18 65.2220 Du 1 RES1 0.0000
@<TRIPOS>BOND
@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE
```

I'm trying to find all the files in my working directory that are missing the numeric line after the `@<TRIPOS>BOND` and move them to another directory. I know this is a simple task, but I am quite new to Linux.

Note: the files vary in length and line numbers, this is why I am "grepping" the line after the `@<TRIPOS>BOND` string.

Here's one of my codes, which I was planning to write in a for loop. It doesn't do the job, but I am showing it to show one of my trials.

```
cat file | grep -A1 '@<TRIPOS>BOND' | awk 'FNR == 2 {print}'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your version of grep supports PCRE mode (`-P`) you could try a multiline match that finds instances of `@<TRIPOS>BOND` that are followed (after only a newline) by `@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE` e.g.

```
grep -lzP '\Q@<TRIPOS>BOND\E\n\Q@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE\E' *
```

The `\Q` and `\E` may be unnecessary in this case but are intended to force literal matching (in case `@`, `>`, `<` have special meaning in the Perl regex syntax). The `-l` tells grep to list the matching files instead of printing the match. You can then use the list of files as an input to the `mv` command e.g.

```
grep -lzP '\Q@<TRIPOS>BOND\E\n\Q@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE\E' * | xargs mv -t /path/to/newdir/
```

#### Additional info

You could express the second part of the match as a *lookahead* but I don't think it has any advantage in this case

```
grep -lzP '\Q@<TRIPOS>BOND\E\n(?=\Q@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE\E)' *
```

Equivalent expressions in `pcregrep` (which is not part of the standard Ubuntu system, but obtainable from the repository) would be something like

```
pcregrep -lM '\Q@<TRIPOS>BOND\E\n\Q@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE\E' *
```

and

```
pcregrep -lM '\Q@<TRIPOS>BOND\E\n(?=\Q@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE\E)' *
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
for file in *.txt; do 
    grep -A1 "@<TRIPOS>BOND" "$file" | grep -q SUBSTR && mv "$file" bad_files/
done
```

#### Explanation:

This will loop through all `.txt` files in the current directory (change to the blob to whatever matches your files) and save each as `$file`. It will then search `$file` for `@<TRIPOS>BOND` and print that and the next line. This is passed through the next `grep` which silently (`-q`) looks for `SUBSTR`, if it finds it, it means that the line after `BOND` is `SUBSTRUCTURE` and not the numeric line you want so it will move the current file to the folder `bad_files`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple:

```
find -type f -exec \
 awk '/@<TRIPOS>BOND/{getline; \
  if ($0 !~ /1  3  5  ar/){\
  printf "mv %s /path/to/move/%s\n", FILENAME, FILENAME}}' {} \; \
| bash
```

Explanation:

- `find -type f`: Find all files in the current working directory
- `awk '/@<TRIPOS>BOND/{getline; \`: find the line inside the file and move to the next line
- `if ($0 !~ /1  3  5  ar/){\`: If the next line is NOT (`!~`) your desired "numeric line"
- `printf "mv %s /path/to/move/%s\n", FILENAME, FILENAME}}' {} \; \`: build an mv command and pipe it to...
- `| bash`: ...bash and execute it.

So the command will mv all file that are not contianing the numeric line to a directory called `/path/to/move/`.

Comment: I think the OP's numeric line can change. I doubt it will be the same for all bonds.

Comment: Then he can replace `if ($0 !~ /1  3  5  ar/)` with `if ($0 ~ /@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE/)`

Comment: Indeed. Or, simpler `if ($1 !~ /^[0-9]$/)`, that way you don't need to worry about multiple spaces or tabs.

Comment: You should change this part `if ($0 !~ /1  3  5  ar/)`

Answer (score 0):

```
nawk '/^@<TRIPOS>BOND/{getline;if( $0 ~ /^@/){print "mv", FILENAME, "../NewLoc/"}}' * | bash
```

Comment: piping to bash is unnecessary, we can use system() function. Please check my answer

Comment: -1 you have a BIG problem, if the file name contains spaces and other funny characters.

Answer (score 0):

The task is quite simple using awk.  Here's my example. I've created two files `file-nm` (for not-missing) and `file-m`(for missing), and `moved` directory for the files that we want to move.

`awk '/@<TRIPOS>BOND/ {getline; if ($0 == "@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE" ) system("mv \""FILENAME"\" moved")}' file-nm file-m`

Here we find the `@<TRIPOS>BOND` string, step into the next line, and check if that line is `@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE`. If it is, we make system call with "mv " the FILENAME of the file that has been found, and " moved" as destination. Here's the result:

```
$ ls
file-m  file-nm  moved


$ awk '/@<TRIPOS>BOND/ {getline; if ($0 == "@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE" ) system("mv \""FILENAME"\" moved")}' file-nm file-m      


$ ls                                                                                                                     
file-nm  moved


$ ls moved                                                                                                               
file-m
```

Comment: You should use double quotes for your filenames in `system (…)`

Comment: @A.B. If I use "FILENAME" , `system` command will literally treat that as `mv FILENAME moved` .  Unquoted FILENAME gets substituted by awk , from the actual file's filename

Comment: `"mv \""FILENAME"\" moved"`

Answer (score 0):

### Using `awk` or `gawk`

```
awk '/@<TRIPOS>BOND/,/@/ {getline; if ($_ ~ /^@/) {printf "%s:%s\n",$_,FILENAME; system ("mv \""FILENAME"\" <bad_files>/$(basename \""FILENAME"\")")} exit}' <file_name>
```

---

*Explanation*

- `/@<TRIPOS>BOND/,/@/`

  We need only the block between `@<TRIPOS>BOND` and the next line starting with `@`
- `getline`

  Read the next line after `@<TRIPOS>BOND`
- `if ($_ ~ /^@/)`

  Check, if the line starts with a `@`

  - `true`

    Print a message

    ```
    printf "%s:%s\n",$_,FILENAME
    ```

    Move the file

    ```
    system ("mv \""FILENAME"\" <bad_files>/$(basename \""FILENAME"\")")
    ```
  - `false`

    Leave the script

    ```
    exit
    ```

---

*Example*

```
$ cat foo
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  2 H18 65.2220 Du 1 RES1 0.0000
@<TRIPOS>BOND
@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE

$ cat bar
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  2 H18 65.2220 Du 1 RES1 0.0000
@<TRIPOS>BOND
 1  3  5  ar
@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE

$ awk '/@<TRIPOS>BOND/,/@/ {getline; if ($_ ~ /^@/) {printf "%s:%s\n",$_,FILENAME; system ("mv \""FILENAME"\" \""FILENAME"\"_moved")} exit}' foo
@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE:foo

$ awk '/@<TRIPOS>BOND/,/@/ {getline; if ($_ ~ /^@/) {printf "%s:%s\n",$_,FILENAME; system ("mv \""FILENAME"\" \""FILENAME"\"_moved")} exit}' bar

$ cat foo_moved 
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  2 H18 65.2220 Du 1 RES1 0.0000
@<TRIPOS>BOND
@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE

$ cat bar_moved
cat: bar_moved: No such file or directory
```